# Force all pages to HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, heroku

I am using Heroku php with SSL on. Everything is setup and https works perfectly.
My domain hosted in Godaddy. Heroku as apache web server.
but http://mysite.com, www.mysite.com will not redirect to https://www.mysite.com
which is what i want.

I had changed the .htaccess file to following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} protected [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} protected2 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} protected3 [NC]
```

I also forward domain to https://www.mysite.com

Comment: Could you add the forward rule as well?

Comment: see this (it works for me) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31467871/setting-up-https-redirects-on-heroku-laravel-instance#

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

[Source](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)

Comment: I have pulled it out of the apache wiki, assumingly it shall work. If you have access to virtual hosts configuration, then use [this](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)

Answer (score 0):

Using a htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Using PHP to direct:

```
  exit(header("location: https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"));
```

Both should work. :-)