# Setting up HTTPS redirects on Heroku Laravel Instance

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ssl, heroku

I have a Laravel 5 build running on an apache Heroku instance and I am trying to make sure all traffic is converted through https, however I am desperately lost.

I have the SSL certificate up and running successfully. However with Heroku you cannot edit the .htaccess file on their server directly. So their recommendation on [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings) is to set up an apache_app.conf and tell Heroku to read it by putting this in the Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -C apache_app.conf public/
```

However when I do this, pretty much any kind of HTTPS rewrite rules I add cause a redirect loop or an application error. Here is my current configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Normal way (in case you need to deploy to NON-heroku)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

#Heroku way
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

#If neither above conditions are met, redirect to https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you add your `apache_app.conf` contents to your question?

Comment: @elithrar Sure, updated. I should note that I was finally able to fix this by adding "DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm" to the top of the apache_conf.php file. I suppose that was the problem. Although I am admittedly out of depth with this stuff.

Comment: You should answer your own question and then mark it as the answer. This fixed my problem exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Adding that code to the public/.htaccess file and removing the "-C apache_app.conf" from the Procfile also does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling redirect by .htaccess I was able to do it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https) method

HttpsProtocol middleware will redirect every web route to the HTTPS protocol

Comment: my routes defined in api.php and web.php does not work in heruko

Comment: return redirect()->secure() doesn't work on my heroku instance. any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

According to Heroku documentation, you must have "TrustProxies" middleware modified to have `$proxies` set as "*"

```php
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    protected $proxies = '*';
// ...
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#trusting-the-load-balancer